# Performing two actions in order

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel

I am creating a swing application.
It consists of calling a function with some time consuming code.

The problem is the "time consuming code" , it is called before the Label's text is set. I want the label to be set before it goes onto the next line.
Why does this occour ?

```
myFunction()
{
  myLabel.setText("Started");
 //time consuming code which creates object of another class
}
```

Note: I did use java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater when starting the entire application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would behoove you to learn about `SwingWorker` which gives you ultimate flexibility when it comes to threading. Here's the short and skinny:

All GUI actions should be on the `Event Dispatch Thread` (EDT for short). All time-consuming tasks should be on background threads. SwingWorker allows you to control which thread you're running code on.

First, to run anything on the EDT, you use this code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        jLabel1.setText("Yay I'm on the EDT.");
    }
});
```

But if you want to run a time-consuming task, that won't do what you need. Instead, you'll need a SwingWorker like this:

```
class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    public Task() {
        /*
         * Code placed here will be executed on the EDT.
        */
        jLabel1.setText("Yay I'm on the EDT.");
        execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        /*
         * Code run here will be executed on a background, "worker" thread that will not interrupt your EDT
         * events. Run your time consuming tasks here.
         *
         * NOTE: DO NOT run ANY Swing (GUI) code here! Swing is not thread-safe! It causes problems, believe me.
        */
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        /* 
         * All code run in this method is done on the EDT, so keep your code here "short and sweet," i.e., not
         * time-consuming.
        */
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            boolean error = false;
            try {
                get(); /* All errors will be thrown by this method, so you definitely need it. If you use the Swing
                        * worker to return a value, it's returned here.
                        * (I never return values from SwingWorkers, so I just use it for error checking).
                        */
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // Handle your error...
                error = true;
            }
            if (!error) {
                /*
                 * Place your "success" code here, whatever it is.
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to launch your SwingWorker with this:

```
new Task();
```

For more info, check out Oracle's documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: a swingworker can be started (aka: calling its execute) from any thread, no need to wrap that into an invokeLater

Comment: @kleopatra, I always wondered that, I just assumed it needed EDT. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @kleopatra, actually, reconsidering what you said: my point was regarding the code inside the constructor of the custom `SwingWorker`. For instance, in all of my `SwingWorker`s, I initialize a loading dialog. I initialize this loading dialog in the constructor of the `SwingWorker` and I close it in `done()`. And I don't think that the constructor will necessarily be executed on the EDT. So, it would need to be called inside of `invokeLater`.

Comment: ahh .. I see, looking only now at your constructor: calling the execute from within is a tad unusual, personal opinion only :-) Yes, the constructor must be called on the EDT, because it configures some components. A lonely execute wouldn't require the EDT.

Comment: Either way: to ensure the constructor code is on the EDT requires invokeLater, no matter where `execute()` is placed, because it doesn't invoke the constructor. But, I've never initialized a `SwingWorker` without immediately calling `execute()`, so I just made a template where `execute()` is inside the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You should run your time consuming code in a separated thread :

```
myFunction(){
    myLabel.setText("Started");
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //time consuming code which creates object of another class
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: `start()` instead of `run()`, I presume.

Comment: @YAT Sorry but this does not help. the label is set a fraction of a second before the thread finishes.

that is the thread still runs before the setting of the label.

Is it because since myFunction is called within swing, so the new Thread is run faster than swing?

Comment: @user2756339 Does not seem very time consuming code if it finishes almost in the same time as changing a label. That said, it would be possible to try to delay it past the label change by pushing the `new Thread() ...` block to the event queue using `invokeLater()`. The repaint manager might still able to mess the plan so it's not guaranteed to work.