# how to notify a thread from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency

I am trying to call my notify my thread from another class but I think I am going about it all wrong. I have read numerous examples of people trying similar things, but I cannot seem to apply it to my code. I think my problem is my synchronized object but I am not sure. Im new to threads so don't humiliate me. Here is an example of my code:

```
public class SendTextOffEdt implements Runnable {
               private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 3000;
               public static String TEXT = "Sent off of EDT\n";
               private TextBox myTextBox;

               //public boolean waitBoolean = false;

               public SendTextOffEdt(TextBox myTextBox) {
                  this.myTextBox = myTextBox;
               }
            @Override
               public void run() {
                   synchronized(this){
                       //while (true) {
                     try {
                       myTextBox.appendTextOffEdt(TEXT);
                         wait();

                     } catch (InterruptedException e) { //******** i changed this from another exception!! 
                     System.out.println("*----------thread interrupted!");
                     myTextBox.appendTextOffEdt(TEXT);
                     }
                  }
               }
}

public class Combat extends JPanel {


private SendTextOffEdt sendTextOffEdt = new SendTextOffEdt(textbox); //just added this      object    

public Combat(){
TestNotify();
}

public void TestNotify(){
        synchronized(sendTextOffEdt){ //added the sendTextOffEdt object here

            sendTextOffEdt.notifyAll();
            System.out.println("has been notified");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wait() is the same as this.wait() and notifyAll() is the same as this.notifyAll(). So you can see that you are calling wait() and notifyAll() on completely separate objects. You must call  notifyAll() on the same object you called wait() on.

Your Combat class needs a reference to your SendTextOffEdt class. Then the Combat class can call notifyAll() on your SendTextOffEdt instance to wake it up.

Comment: I edited my code to do what you suggested. Let me know if that works. I added the sendtextoffedt object to the combat class and referenced it. It may help if I told you I am just simply trying to print a string when the thread is notified. Does this help?

Comment: @CameronRoberson You don't have any code after your wait() call. When SendTextOffEdt wakes up, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I added the code in my program (not the one here) and it still doesnt do anything. It may have something todo with the eventdispatch thread. The Combat class is called from an action event, which I believe means its on the EDT correct? Do I need to have a try catch statement to check for this? Let me know. Thanks Jay,

Comment: @CameronRoberson The problem could be any number of things. I can't do much else without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I have posted another question with the code. Could you take a look at it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239312/how-to-update-a-thread-from-another-class
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve maximum control over threading; EDT (for `Swing`) vs background threads (for time-consuming processes), you must master the `SwingWorker` class. Creating `Runnable`s and using `synchronized` isn't, in my experience, for typical application development.

Read my answer in this thread for more information: [Performing two actions in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783513/performing-two-actions-in-order/18786207#18786207).

You can also read more from the Oracle docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

To brief you on what it says: `SwingWorker` has two methods: `doInBackground()` which always runs OFF the EDT, and `done()` which always runs on the EDT.

WHEN I CODE: I always initialize a loading dialog in the constructor of the `SwingWorker`, run my background code, and prompt the user on the outcome of the background process (whether that's a success message, loading the data into a table, etc).

Just a note: I wouldn't focus on the `publish()` and `process()` methods quite yet until you've mastered the `SwingWorker` threading.